# Freemarker template error handling with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using Freemarker template with Spring MVC. Is there a way to return HTTP Status 500 if there is any error rendering the template?

Currently I am using attempt block to handle error, but would like to throw Internal Server error and allow web server to redirect to a default error page

```
<#attempt>
  attempt block
<#recover>
  recover block
</#attempt>
```

Below is my **servlet-context.xml**

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="cache" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="" />
    <beans:property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
    <beans:property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: What does Spring MVC do if the template throws an exception?

Comment: @ddekany: once controller delegates request to view, view errors are not handled by Spring MVC. Here view is created using freemarker template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below change in servlet-context.xml resolved the issue. Now it throws HTTP 500 error which is intercepted by web server and I am able to mast the message by redirecting to pre-defined error page.

```
<beans:bean id="freemarkerConfig"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/" />
        <beans:property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="template_exception_handler">rethrow</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: So the problem was that you were in `debug` mode (development mode that saves you from from digging the logs), which is the default (sadly, a legacy...). Note that if you were using FreeMarker 2.3.23, it says on the top of the error message that "FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!)", so you could resolve this with less time loss.

Comment: @ddekany: I could not locate FreeMarker 2.3.23 in maven. Is it in development stage?

Comment: Sorry... I mean to say 2.3.22. (And yes, 2.3.23 is still under development.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the java-based equivalent configuration:

```
@Bean 
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws TemplateException { 
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer(); 
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/ftl/");

    Properties settings = new Properties();
    settings.setProperty(freemarker.template.Configuration.TEMPLATE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_KEY, "rethrow");
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
    return freeMarkerConfigurer; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to change the mode from "debug" to "rethrow" is to configure it in your application.properties:

```
spring.freemarker.settings.template_exception_handler=rethrow
```