# Freemarker template rendering errors in spring boot returns 200 OK

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I want Freemarker template errors to respond with status 500 and thereby make Spring render my default error page for internal server errors. However no matter how I try to configure Freemaker `template_exception_handler` the reponse is never 500.

The default exception handler method is `DEBUG` which yields a message/stacktrace in the errorneous template while the rest of the template (until the error) is rendered.

Setting the handler to `RETHROW` hides the message/stacktrace but results in partly rendered templates.

Setting the handler to `IGNORE` renderes the template in its full skipping fields that could not be parsed.

All of the above throws an exception that is visible on the server. Debugging Springs `BasicErrorController` the exception is handled - but the response from the BasicErrorController is still status 200.

I tried implementing my own ErrorHandlingController that basically just maps to `/error` and renders a ModelAndView with status 500 set. Still the response is 200 and the template is rendered.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426788/freemarker-template-error-handling-with-spring-mvc) answer the solution is to set the template exception handler configuration to `RETRHOW` - but as mentioned above this doesn't provide the expected result.

I'm shooting blanks now and don't know what else to try. Any suggestions?

**Desired result**: When rendering throws a TemplateException Spring should respond with Internal Server error HTTP status code 500 and render my error page for this. (Which by the way works for any other type of exception that occurs on the backend...)

Spring boot version: 2.0.1.RELEASE
Spring version: 5.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: It says btw. in the last part of the stack trace rendered on the server: "----] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
"

Comment: Setting it to rethrow is the most correct setting. Then, the exception is handed over to Spring boot's exception handler, which should either show the error page (`src/main/resources/templates/error.ftl`) if defined, or show a default whitelabel error page. 

You say the exception is handled in BasicErrorController, but I can't see that it has code for doing so. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @tobb I mean that the BasicErrorController is responsible for rendering the error page with the required errorAttributes - however it doesn't render the error page rather the page that is errorneous with a statuscode 200.

Comment: @user7294900 - it is not a duplicate. I reference the exact same post as a potential answer. The "rethrow" setting works how ever the error handling doesn't and Spring reponds with 200 OK even in case of template errors...

Comment: Could you try to change to Spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE? Found an issue that might be the cause of this, which seems to only occur in 2.0.1 (and will be fixed in 2.0.2 as far as I can tell). https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12787

Comment: Will indeed try. It is not deployed as war however - but i'll give a go none the less!

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170586/how-to-disable-errorpagefilter-in-spring-boot

Comment: Tried that already - no luck...